# Can i group controls together?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to group some `TextView` together, to show/hide them together.
Preferably that the space in the view is available for other controls which are placed below the grouped textviews

How can I do that?

p.s.:
In .Net i would use a `Panel` or a `Groupbox`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` (or other `ViewGroup` like `RelativeLayout`) and put `TextView` (and other component) inside it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**From code**

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //to show it
```

or

```
container.setVisibility(View.GONE); //to hide it
```

Comment: Ah, ok, and i can put multiple `LinearLayout`s in a scrollview? I assumed that i can only use one layout per screen/form

Comment: A ScrollView can contains only one LinearLayout (or other ViewGroup) but inside it you can use multiple LinearLayout. Beware nested ViewGroup (for performance). I suggest to improve your knowledge of the RelativeLayout that can simplify the rendering tree of the activity.

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap your TextViews in a ViewGroup (like FrameLayout). Then you can put other views below / above this ViewGroup, and show/hide the ViewGroup so all the Views inside it will be shown/hidden.